# Reference request: Stallings-Epstein-Waldhausen construction

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, differential-topology, 3-manifolds

I am looking for a reference for the **Stallings-Epstein-Waldhausen construction** (constructing an incompressible surface in a 3-manifold from a nontrivial splitting of the fundamental group).

I know of Proposition 2.3.1 in the following article, but was hoping for a more comprehensive / textbook-like treatment.

Marc Culler and Peter B. Shalen: Varieties of Group Representations and Splittings of 3-Manifolds. Annals of Mathematics, Vol. 117, No. 1 (Jan., 1983), pp. 109-146.

My goal is to find out under which conditions the resulting incompressible surface is orientable.

Comment: The resulting surface is always 2-sided by construction, so if the ambient 3-manifold is orientable, so is the surface.

Comment: Since your question is "under which conditions the resulting incompressible surface is orientable", it might be better to edit that into the title, so that it is clear in what way this is not just a reference request (not that there's anything wrong with a reference request!).

Comment: What kind of splitting are you referring to? For example, a free product decomposition corresponds to a connect-sum decomposition so you don't get an incompressible surface from that.  I suppose it depends on your definition of "incompressible".

Comment: @RyanBudney: splitting as a nontrivial HNN extension or amalgamated free product as in Serre-Bass theory. The connected sum decomposition should give the 2-sphere along which the parts are glued, I guess.

Comment: Thank you all so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an answer to your first question: You can find an exposition of the pull-back construction in Scott's notes "[An introduction to 3-manifolds](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1617/math6071b/scott_An%20Introduction%20to%203-manifolds-1974.pdf)".

As an answer to your second question: If the group we are splitting over is not free, then we can detect the orientability of the surface by abelianising the group.  If the group is free, then we are obtaining a surface with boundary.  As HJRW notes, the surface obtained is always two-sided.  Thus it suffices to know that $M^3$, the ambient three-manifold, is orientable.  If $M^3$ is not orientable, there is still a way to detect the orientation of the splitting surface, by lifting to the orientation double cover and seeing how much of the edge group lifts.